# Как сделать чтобы верхняя панель google chrome (android) при загрузке страницы окрашивались в нужный цвет

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Наверное, уже многие сталкивались с такой фишкой, что при загрузке страницы шапка браузера окрашивается в цвет, сайта. Как это сделано, не пойму.
Никаких статей найти не удалось. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

> [chrome toolbar color](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chrome%20toolbar%20color)

2. Идём по первой [ссылке](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android)
3. Узнаём, что, видимо, в `HEAD` страницы надо добавить

   ```
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
   ```
4. Также, из гугла можно вытащить статью с хабра: [Как покрасить вкладку Chrome](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277753/)